# Output content of a text file on a web page

Tags: html, include

I have an **offline** html file that contains documentation and I have to output content of text file (in my case it is source code).  Is there a way to include content of this file to html page, using only client-side feature (HTML itself or JS)?

### Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    p.source_code
    {
        font-family:"Courier New"
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Some content
        </p>
        <p class="source_code">
            <!-- place for output content of file main.cpp -->
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        printf("Hello World");
    }
```

I want my page in browser looks like

```
    Some content

    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        printf("Hello World");
    }
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a way of doing this without some kind of script.

Comment: It's not possible in any simple way. frames are a possibility, but the could have nasty side effects.

Comment: @shambulator: flickering, awkward scrolling etc, it's like watching the page out of a window, you can try to make it as seamless as possible, but it's not very easy.

Comment: it's easy to avoid some of them `<iframe width=100% scrolling=no frameborder=no src="main.cpp" style="border: 0;" seamless>`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use an `iframe` if both the HTML file and the source file are local:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="the-file.txt">
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uhhhhhm. From my answer: "if both the HTML file and the source file are local". It will only request the local machine. @jasonjifly Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, if the html file is local, src can be set to local file.